# Viewport perspective not indicating what view I'm in

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, properties

Even though i know the viewports and what num.keys they correspond to by heart blender is not showing what perspective i'm on in the top left corner, even if a start a new scene. The only way i been able to get it display is to load factory settings which means i have to activate all my add-ons again.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the user preferences (located in *'File'* menu in 2.79), go to *'Interface'* tab and change *'View Name'*.

[image]

For 2.8, I think this is no more in the preferences but in the *'Viewport Overlays'*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i'm not even sure how it got turned off in the first place.